# Is the energy change $\delta Q$ form 16C-15C the same as 72C to 73C?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

As the tempreature change is the same. so the amount of energy change should also be same. According to the foumula 
$$\Delta Q=m s \Delta T$$
So no matter form what temperature to temperature change is as long as the $\Delta T$ is the same the amount of energy should also be the same right?

But when I asked my college professor he said that it is different. He gave an example that it is difficult to climb a stair after climbing 10 floors but it is easy to climb a stair at the Ground floor. so we need to spend less energy.

I disagree, or is it true?

Comment: Except that, for the moment, you are comparing a change of $-1 ^o C$ ($16 ^o C \to 15^o C$ with $+1^o C$ ($72 ^o C \to 73^o C$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are assuming is that the heat capacity remains constant as the temperature changes which is not completely accurate.  For example for water, to raise the temperature of water from 15C to 16C requires 4.1855 J whereas to raise one gram from 72C to 73C requires 4.192 J.  Not exactly the same.  See [engineering toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-thermal-properties-d_162.html) for data.

Comment: So the problem is that the heat capacity changes with temperature. I thought the heat capacity of the materials remained same like the resisitivity of materials. It cleared my doubt.

Comment: Lots of properties of materials change with temperature.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to climb another flight of stairs after climbing ten. I would be exhausted. But nevertheless, the additional potential energy needed to get one level higher is just the same. If it was different, there is an experiment you could do:

Take the other person into the elevator of a large building. Go up to some level but don't let them see which level. Exit the elevator and take the stairs up another level. If the hypotheses was true, one could determine which level one was one by measuring the work needed to climb the flight of stairs. Except for a building which rises into space, where gravity would be weaker, you will not be able to feel a difference in going from $1 \to 2$ and $10 \to 11$.

Same goes for the temperature. The heat $Q$ is linear in the temperature $T$ by your equation above. This is not always the case as the specific heat can change with the temperature. This is especially the case when you have a phase transition.

Either way, using the equation that you have, an fixed increase in $\Delta T$ will give the same $\Delta Q$, no matter which value the temperature actually has.